# package AlertDialog does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I got email from google that

> SSL Error Handler For more information on how to address WebView SSL
> Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

I am using react native and webview in my android app. In file `RNCWebViewMangere.java` and in function `onReceivedSslError`I have put alert dialog to warn user like this

```
 public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView webView, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab1Activity.this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
    switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
        case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
            message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
            message = "The certificate has expired.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
            message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
            message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
            break;
    }

    message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
    alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

While building my app, I am getting errors

> package AlertDialog does not exist

So how to properly import alertDialog library in my app?
I tried with

```
import androidx.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

But it is not working

Any help is appreicated.
Thank you

Comment: In case android jetpack does not exist in your project, you can try `android.app.AlertDialog`.

Comment: not it is showing ccannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity

Comment: import android.app.AppCompatActivity; is not recognised

Comment: You need to use `android.app.Activity` and `android.app.AlertDialog` together, `android.app.AppCompatActivity` is not an existing class.

Comment: if I use `import android.app.Activity;` (which is gray unused import statement) then I have `cannot find symbol class Tab1Activity`